# Querying BLOB field from Oracle Database with PHP

Tags: php, sql, oracle, blob

I have a PHP script that takes an image from an Oracle database and saves it into a MySQL database.

It worked fine until I upgraded to PHP 5.3.3 from PHP 5.1.6.  The part that queries the Oracle database no longer works.  It can query all fields apart from the image field.  I believe it is a BLOB.

For instance, the below code outputs **Resource id #6**

```
$sql2 = "SELECT CREATIVE FROM creative WHERE id = 10314612";
    foreach($oci->query($sql2) as $row2) {
        echo $row2['CREATIVE']; 
    }
```

Comment: From [PHP doc](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.oci-fetch-array.php): "By default, LOB columns are returned as [LOB descriptors](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.OCI-Lob.php)." Try something like `$rows["CREATIVE"]->load()`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but that gives me:

Fatal error: Call to a member function load() on a non-object

Comment: What does `var_dump($row2['CREATIVE'])` say?

Comment: resource(6) of type (stream)

Comment: How is your OCI wrapper implemented? What does `current` give in your `$oci->query`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've finally fixed it.

The code now looks like this:

```
$stmt = $dbcon->prepare( 'SELECT CREATIVE FROM creative WHERE id = 10314612'); 
$stmt->execute(); 
$res = $stmt->fetchAll( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC ); 

for( $i=0; $i<count($res); $i++ ){ 
  $data = stream_get_contents( $res[$i]['CREATIVE'] ); 
}
```

Thanks for your help Passerby.

I don't understand why it works.  I just copied the above from one of the examples on php.net

If anyone knows why, it would be great if they could post it here :)